# How to encrypt the http request sent to server?

Tags: javascript, encryption, httprequest

Is it possible to hide the contents (or encrypt it) of an HTTP request so that no other than authorize person can view it ?? 
For example, if one user is just submitting a data to in Login page even if using the http post, then also it is possible to see the contents like username and password which are contained in request headers in firebug kind of tools.

I know that encryption algorithm at client side may be used but still data goes in HTTP request is visible.

Any solutions ???
Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https

Comment: and the reason you are NOT considering HTTPS is?

Comment: The data you send will always be visible over http, but if it is encrypted it can't be understood by listening parties which do not have enough data to decrypt it.

Comment: hmm.. what do you mean by visible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard method for encrypting web traffic is an SSL certificate. Their use is easily recognized by the **https** protocol specification.  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https

SSL Certificates can be purchased easily online. Below are a couple of vendors that I use:

http://www.comodo.com

http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/index.html

Comment: Thanks for reply...
Can you please guide how can I switch from HTTP to HTTPS ?? Also something that may help me to "implement" it...

Comment: @adn295, The scope of your question is **huge** and would require several other questions to be answered. I suggest doing some research on your own and attempting to figure it out. Once you've gone as far as you can go, post another question on SO and we'll help you the best we can.

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends a lot on the setup you are looking for. If you just want to prevent anyone from listening in on the traffic, use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) for the requests.

If you want to encrypt the data you are sending with a specific password, check out the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/).

Comment: @Bruno I'm not proposing to replace HTTPS with something self-built. But the poster asked for a way encrypt data in a way, that only an `authorized person` would be able to see it. And that is not possible using HTTPS in a JavaScript setting. You need to create a symmetric encryption using a key only the authorized person knows.

Comment: my apologies for pasting a link without context. I don't disagree with you, I thought a bit more information about the problems with JS crypto could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You must use **HTTPS** protocol